# How to show an image on the LCD of ARM 9 processor?

Tags: image, arm, lcd

I need to display an image on the LCD of the ARM 9 board. The processor is ARM926EJ-S and I'm running the board on Windows. I'm using Code Composer Studio v4. Are there any libraries that I can use for this purpose?

I managed to show colours on the LCD by using the evmam1808_lcd_raster.c. Is displaying images similar to this? Here is the code I used:

```
#define LCD_WIDTH    320
#define LCD_HEIGHT   240
#define COLOR_BLUE   0x001f

int x,y;
RASTER_init();
for(y = 0; y < LCD_HEIGHT; ++y){
    for(x = 0; x < LCD_WIDTH; ++x)
        RASTER_plot(x, y, COLOR_BLUE);
}
```

Do I need to read the image file and then display it on the screen or is there another way of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The processor is largely irrelevant. What 'board' is being used?

Comment: Am1808 board sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: am1808 is a chip, not a board with an lcd connected.  is this the zoom am1808 evm board?  need to always put those things in the question as it is all specific to that board and even more the libraries you are using.  and the answer is "it depends" on the libraries you are using and what libraries are available to you or if you want to make your own drivers, etc.

Comment: what did the board tech support folks say when you asked them?